# how to add a new column in already existing table in the java class file?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have my collegue's java web application, where i was asked to edit the table that has been existing, where i have to add a new column.
Everytime i try to add a new column, the alignment of the table changes.
before adding.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9gQL.png)

after

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Us3.png)

now the code goes something like this

```
data="<table id='v_esTable' class='table table-bordered color-bordered-table inverse-bordered-table'><thead style=\"background-color: #064b87\">"
                 + "<tr><th class=\"text-white\">JEN No.</th >"
                    + "<th class=\"text-white\">Village Name</th>"
                       +"<th class=\"text-white\">Village Name</th>"
                
                    + "<th class=\"text-white\">Applicant Name</th>"
                    + "<th class=\"text-white\">Awardee Name</th><th class=\"text-white\">Relation To Awardee</th><th class=\"text-white\">Award Date</th>"
                    + "<th class=\"text-white\">Awardee No</th><th class=\"text-white\">Land Extent</th><th class=\"text-white\">Job Status</th>"
                    + "<th class=\"text-white\">ITI Dicipline</th><th class=\"text-white\">Diploma Dicipline</th><th class=\"text-white\">Engg. Dicipline</th>"
```

Comment: Why don't you use a template engine? (e.g. thymeleaf)

Comment: You need to look at the CSS being applied to that table.

Comment: wait i will check that css file

Comment: and what is the template engine Nick?

Comment: Nick its an already existing web application and i just have to edit the table